# What is the equivalent of $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', ..) in ui-router for Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have experience with ui-router for Angular 1 and now I want to know how to listen `$stateChangeStart` in ui-router-ng2.

Please let me know how the following Angular 1 piece of code can be done in Angular 2.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, next) {});
```

Comment: Did you tried the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice Plunkr for example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/k8PgPKRNu0llT521p5R5?p=preview

On ui-router-ng2 you have service(TransitionService) with all states life cycle:

1) you need to inject the service on your constructor:

```
import {TransitionService} from "ui-router-ng2";
constructor(private transitionService:TransitionService) {}
```

2) callback function:

```
transitionService.onStart({}, ()=>{
   console.log("state changed");
})
```

On the first value you can put conditions for example:

```
transitionService.onStart({from: 'home', to: 'other'}, ()=>{
   console.log("state changed");
})
```

(the callback will call only when the current state is 'home' and next state  'other')

** you also can call onSuccess, onError, onEnter, onFinish and more...

i hope you find it helpful,

Good Luck!

Comment: All about the Transition Service: https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/docs/latest/classes/transition.transitionservice.html

Comment: One warning about adding Transition Hooks in a component: they are not automatically cleaned up, so they have to be explicitly cleaned up if the component will ever be destroyed using `ngOnDestroy`

Comment: My recommendation is not adding Transition Hooks in a component. 
It is better to adding Transition Hooks in services, Where constructor called only once.